# React.js implement UI effects after mounting

Tags: javascript, dom, coffeescript, reactjs

Let's suppose I have a `React` class, which has a components - fields with [autosize.js](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) and [bootstrap form helpers phone](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/phone/) libraries. There is a trouble. Because of these few (and a lot of another) libs rendered exactly after DOM is loaded, I need to manually implement these libraries to components - something like that:

```
componentDidMount: ->
  phoneInput = $(React.findDOMNode(@refs.phone)) # found appropriate field
  phoneInput.bfhphone(phoneInput.data()) # approve bfh-phone for this field
```

How can I make my React classes already use these UI libraries before mounting them to the DOM?

Comment: Until the DOM element has been created, there's nothing to attach to. The callback you've used is the correct place to wire up to a library that wasn't designed for React.

Comment: Hm... I think anybody has created a library exactly for this behaviour of react. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate with a non-React DOM library, as @WiredPrairie said, you'll need to utilize `componentDidMount`. However, you can encapsulate that logic in a custom component, so you only have to do it once. For example, you used the code:

```coffeescript
componentDidMount: ->
  phoneInput = $(React.findDOMNode(@refs.phone))
  phoneInput.bfhphone(phoneInput.data())
```

Imagine you had several such fields. You could create a special component called `BFHPhoneInput` or something that does it for you automatically:

```coffeescript
BFHPhoneInput = React.createClass
  componentDidMount: ->
    input = $(React.findDOMNode(@refs.input))
    input.bfhphone(input.data())

  render: ->
    props =
      ref: "input"
    # copy all this.props to props
    props[key] = val for own key, val of this.props
    React.DOM.input props
```

(I'm not familiar with the `bfhphone` plugin so you may need to do more than this to integrate it properly.)

Now you can use it multiple times without worrying about the plugin:

```coffeescript
MyComponent = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div {},
      BFHPhoneInput {value: @state.phone1, onChange: @handlePhone1Change}
      BFHPhoneInput {value: @state.phone2, onChange: @handlePhone2Change}
```